# JavaScript - Persistent data in function between calls?

Tags: javascript, function, persistence

I want to call a function with an argument and store the value so that next time I call that function without arguments it uses the last argument that was set. Is this possible with JavaScript?

Edit: Here's more info on what I'm trying to achieve...

```
var track = 0;
$.getJSON('songsMetadata.json', function(data){
    appendData(data);
});
player.bind("ended", function(){
    track++
    appendData();
});
function appendData(data){
    /* Here I want to populate 
     the inside 'data' argument 
    only once (in the callback of 
    getJSON) and use that same
    data in the 'player.bind' 
    callback */

    //Some code to append data[track] to an HTML list
}
```

Comment: yeah, sure it can be done but if you could please give me a bit more information, i could write you an example. what will the argument be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Creating a function with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161671/javascript-creating-a-function-with-state)

Comment: You may be interested in [iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: @MolikMiah the argument will be an array that I get from an Ajax call to a JSON file. The array contains mp3s metadata from an HTML 5 playlist that I coded. What I want to do is append this data gradually into the HTML (showing the metadata as the playlist plays each song). I'm still a little bit confused about asynchronous code

Comment: You can use either of the existing answers to accomplish this. Based on my answer for example - you just have to wrap `appendData` in the wrapper function. `var cachedAppend = cacheFn(appendData);` then use `cacheAppend` in all places you would use `appendData`. This normalizes `appendData` so it always gets called with some argument, either the one being passed, or the last argument to have been passed (as you specified in your question).

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a reference to the last acceptable argument in the enclosing scope. For example:

```js
var ref;

function foo (arg) {
  if (!arg) { // or arg === undefined if you want to be safe
    arg = ref;
  } else {
    ref = arg;
  }

  // actual function behavior here
  console.log(arg);
}

foo(); // undefined
foo(2); // 2
foo(); // 2
foo(3); // 3
foo(); // 3
```

If you want to repeat this behavior, you might want to consider writing a wrapper function to cache an accepted function's argument. For example:

```js
function cacheFn (fn) {
  var ref;
  
  return function (arg) {
    if (!arg) {
      arg = ref;
    } else {
      ref = arg;
    }
    
    return fn(arg);
  }
}

function foo (arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

var cachedFoo = cacheFn(foo);

cachedFoo(2);
cachedFoo();
cachedFoo(3);
cachedFoo();
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this code. Could you explain what is doing exactly?  For instance what happens when you return a function? And why do you pass the foo function to cacheFn? I know this code works but I'm genuinely interested in why

Comment: @medicengonzo think of `cachedFn` as an attachment you can make to a function such that it performs the same functionality but with an added benefit. The first thing we do is declare a variable `ref` which will (internally) be used to store the latest argument passed into the function. We then return a function which wraps the function being passed in (in your case `appendData`). This willl, eventually run your function, but first we do a bit of logic to determine of an argument has been passed. If so we pass that argument straight in and update `ref`, if not we pass in `ref`.

Comment: The benefit of this pattern is that your function, `appendData`, or any other function that you want to use this behavior on, is "dumb" to the whole process. It can concern itself only with the logic it needs to accomplish.

Comment: Oh yeah I get it now. Thanks a lot! I learned something new today! :)

Comment: @medicengonzo glad to hear it! I would consider looking at Jonas's solution as well, mine is restricted to a single argument, his would work for multiple arguments (is more generalized).

Comment: Thanks I'll be sure to check it out. I haven't started learning ES6 yet so it's a little bit more confusing but I will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In a more general way:

```
function enclose(func) {
 let args = [];
 return function (...passed) {
   if(passed.length) args = passed;
   func(...args);
 };
}
```

Usecase:

```
const log = enclose(console.log.bind(console));
log(5,1);
log();
```

Comment: Yep this is a more general soln for `n` args also assuming es6 is available. If not could easily replicate the spread behavior with `arguments` and `apply`. +1

Comment: @damon +1 for the general idea ;)