# Limit document.elementsFromPoint( x, y ) to SVG id only, and print out list of elements by ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How do I make document.elementsFromPoint( x, y ) only return elements within SVG?
How do I get a list of SVG elements only, and apply hover changes to only those SVG elements?

Finally, this will be overlaid on a very large SVG with thousands of points.  Is there a more efficient way to only apply the color changes on hover, and remove color changes on just those elements on mouse move? (The approach in the fiddle applies it to ALL SVG elements, which means thousands of changes with every mouse move on a document with more elements)

In this code, I tried svg.elementsFromPoint( x, y ) in this code.
I was reading about Shadow Roots and tried to .createShadowRoot() on the SVG but that didn't work; and I'm not even sure if that is the right approach.

https://jsfiddle.net/g8p60vy7/

```
(function() {
    const svg = document.querySelector('#Shapes'),
          output = document.querySelector('#test');

    function printElement(elm) {
        var id = elm.id ? ' id="' + elm.id + '"' : "";
        return "<" + elm.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + ">";
    }
    var shapes = svg.querySelectorAll('ellipse,rect,polygon');
    shapes.forEach( (el) => {
        el.dataset.default_fill = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
        el.style.fill = el.dataset.default_fill;
    } );

    function hitTest(e) {

                const x = e.clientX,
              y = e.clientY,
              current_hovereds = document.elementsFromPoint( x, y );
                shapes.forEach( (el) => el.style.fill = el.dataset.default_fill );
        
            var orderedcolors = ["rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(75, 0, 130, 0.2)", " rgba(148, 0, 211, 0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.01)"];
        
                current_hovereds.forEach( (el, i) => el.style.fill =  orderedcolors[ i ]);
        //not working to print element
        output.textContext = current_hovereds.map(printElement).join(' ');

    }
    

    svg.addEventListener('mousemove', hitTest);
    svg.addEventListener('touchmove', hitTest);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the list of all the `shapes` you are targeting, simply filter out the result of `document.elementsFromPoint` to the ones that are inside this `shapes` list.

```
(function() {
  const svg = document.querySelector('#Shapes');
  const output = document.querySelector('#test');

  function printElement(elm) {
    var id = elm.id ? ' id="' + elm.id + '"' : "";
    return "<" + elm.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + ">";
  }
  // convert to Array for easy filtering
  const shapes = [...svg.querySelectorAll('ellipse,rect,polygon')];
  shapes.forEach((el) => {
    el.dataset.default_fill = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    el.style.fill = el.dataset.default_fill;
  });

  function hitTest(e) {
    const orderedcolors = ["rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(75, 0, 130, 0.2)", " rgba(148, 0, 211, 0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.01)"];
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    const current_hovereds = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)
      // keep only our shapes
      .filter(el => shapes.includes(el));

    shapes.forEach((el) => el.style.fill = el.dataset.default_fill);

    current_hovereds.forEach((el, i) => el.style.fill = orderedcolors[i]);
    // had a typo
    output.textContent = current_hovereds.map(printElement).join(' ');

  }
  svg.addEventListener('mousemove', hitTest);
  svg.addEventListener('touchmove', hitTest);
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85dv69k3/

Comment: Thanks so much! Both responses are incredibly helpful.  This seems to still apply a fill to ALL shapes.. not just the current_hovereds, which might cause performance issues when there are thousands of spots? https://jsfiddle.net/mmmd81/f58ak1e9/26/  
Would it make sense to just store current_hovereds as last_hovereds at end of function?  Next time function runs, check if last_hovereds contains data and clear fill on last_hovereds?  That way it doesn't change thousands of elements with every mouse move...

Comment: Changing to the same value won't have any effect, so you should be fine, the only thing being looping over all these elements (but thousands should still be ok). Iff you face perfs issues then yes, you can store the previously hovered ones and only loop over these.

Comment: Thank you -- is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477420/javascript-persistent-data-in-function-between-calls this how I would have to do it?  Store the data in a console and keep updating console?  Would this still work on mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, just keep it in a variable, yes. https://jsfiddle.net/nyvgx0L3/

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out from your fiddle, you are not aiming for elements that are children of the `<svg>` element, but for elements that can be colored in with a `fill` property. They have common base class, `SVGGeometryElement`. You can just test for that:

```
const current_hovereds =document.elementsFromPoint( x, y ).filter(el => {
    return el instanceof SVGGeometryElement;
});
```

Not that Internet Explorer does not implement this class. If you need copmpatibility for that, you need to list all relevant elements:

```
    return el instanceof SVGPathElement ||
    el instanceof SVGRectElement ||
    el instanceof SVGCircleElement ||
    el instanceof SVGEllipseElement ||
    el instanceof SVGLineElement ||
    el instanceof SVGPolylineElement ||
    el instanceof SVGPolygonElement ||
    el instanceof SVGTextContentElement;
```

For the text output, it's a simple typo: `output.textContent`, not `output.textContext`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Both responses are incredibly helpful.  This seems to still apply a fill to ALL shapes.. not just the current_hovereds, which might cause performance issues when there are thousands of spots? https://jsfiddle.net/mmmd81/f58ak1e9/26/  
Would it make sense to just store current_hovereds as last_hovereds at end of function?  Next time function runs, check if last_hovereds contains data and clear fill on last_hovereds?  That way it doesn't change thousands of elements with every mouse move...